# How to use Awesome windows manager via TigerVncServer?

Tags: awesome-wm, tightvnc

Ok, I install Devuan Linux without GUI on QEMU and then install Awesome, then install VNC by this [instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04) step 1 and step 2:

this is ok, but when I connect via vnc viewer for my virtual pc I see next:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEPlX.png) (only white noise instead of an image)

this is my config in: `$ ~/.vnc/xstartup`

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
startawesome &
```

someone know any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Awesome the two executables were awesome and awesome-client, so I just changed my window manager line to "awesome &" and that was that.  I'm on Ubuntu but I doubt the executable name would be different on other flavors.